# Blurry offset paths when canvas is scaled under hardware acceleration

Tags: android, graphics, hardware-acceleration

My application uses a canvas that I scale so that I can specify path points in meters instead of pixels. When I scale the canvas, then draw a line using `path.lineTo()`, with hardware acceleration on, the line is blurry and offset. This does not happen with hardware acceleration off or with `canvas.drawLine()`.

Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
package com.example.canvasproblem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    class MyView extends View {
        Paint pen = new Paint();
        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            pen.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            pen.setStrokeWidth(1f); // 1 meters wide
            //this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            float width_meter = 10.0f; // width of canvas in meters
            float width_pxl = canvas.getWidth(); // width of canvas in pixels
            float height_pxl = canvas.getHeight(); // height of canvas in pixels

            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(width_pxl/2, height_pxl/2); // make center of canvas (0,0)
            canvas.scale(width_pxl/width_meter, width_pxl/width_meter); // convert to meters

            // path
            Path path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(0, 0);
            path.lineTo(0, 4);
            canvas.drawPath(path, pen);

            // line
            canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 4, pen);

            canvas.restore();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem output (the correct drawLine() is shown on top of lineTo()):

[Screenshot.png](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~woodward/images/Screenshot.png)

The hardware is a 1024x768 tablet, running android 4.1.1. The processor is a Rockchip RK30.

My preference is to use Path's with hardware acceleration, for rounded joins between points and speed. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong to create this problem. Thank you

Be gentle, this is my first post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a limitation of the hardware accelerated renderer. Paths are rasterized at their native size before transform. In your case, the Path is transformed into a 1x4 texture. That texture is then scaled at draw time. To work around this, scale your Path directly by using `Path.transform(Matrix)`. You can also use scaled coordinates when building the path.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you know if this is a bug, or is that the desired behavior?

Comment: It is the intended behavior, but not the desired behavior :) This is something I plan on fixing in a future release of Android. We will also provide better documentation on what's supported and what's not supported in the hardware renderer across multiple API levels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, it's a map-drawing app and I'll be zooming into the map (changing the canvas scale) and keeping the line widths constant, so I don't have the luxury of calling `Path.transform()`. It's ok; performance was ok without hardware acceleration.

Comment: An update on this answer after 7 years...
The documentation was updated to specify what scaling operations are supported under what API level: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel#scaling
This documentation suggests path scaling was fixed in Android 28 (Pie, released 2018).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Romain Guy's answer, here is a wrapper for the drawPath() method that produces the same results for hardware acceleration on and off. It only handles the case where the x & y scaling in the existing matrix are the same, and it might not be the most efficient.

```
void drawPath(Canvas canvas, Path path, final Paint pen) {
    canvas.save();

    // get the current matrix
    Matrix mat = canvas.getMatrix();

    // reverse the effects of the current matrix
    Matrix inv = new Matrix();
    mat.invert(inv);
    canvas.concat(inv);

    // transform the path
    path.transform(mat);

    // get the scale for transforming the Paint
    float[] pts = {0, 0, 1, 0}; // two points 1 unit away from each other
    mat.mapPoints(pts);
    float scale = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pts[0]-pts[2], 2) + Math.pow(pts[1]-pts[3], 2));

    // copy the existing Paint
    Paint pen2 = new Paint();
    pen2.set(pen);

    // scale the Paint
    pen2.setStrokeMiter(pen.getStrokeMiter()*scale);
    pen2.setStrokeWidth(pen.getStrokeWidth()*scale);

    // draw the path
    canvas.drawPath(path, pen2);

    canvas.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get around this issue as I've found is to draw the `Path`s to another `Canvas` that is backed by a cache bitmap, and then draw that bitmap to the passed `Canvas`. This eliminates the blurring and offsets in my situation.

Comment: Yes. Drawing to a bitmap will use the software renderer. Which does not have this fault.