# Android API 23 blurry vector drawable

Tags: android, svg, vector-graphics

My emulator running on API 23 rendered the vector drawable / SVG blurry but it is very clear in emulator running on API 26. I was told that the SVG was exported from Sketch and I have tried flatten the image but the problem still persist.

Is there any other solutions I can try to solve the rendering issue on API 23? It would be great if anyone can tell me why it happens on API 23 (I have never tried the API below 23)

Thank you

API 26

[image][image]

API 23

**Update:**
Strange thing is if I override the drawable when I import it at vector asset, the drawable renders flawlessly. Am I allowed to modify the width and height of the vector drawable?

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="360dp" // 24dp before override
    android:height="640dp"  // 24dp before override
    android:viewportWidth="360"
    android:viewportHeight="640">
```

Comment: Are you using android:src or app:srcCompat?

Comment: Can you post your VectorDrawable, please?  I suspect your issue is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090607/blurry-offset-paths-when-canvas-is-scaled-under-hardware-acceleration  But would need to see the VectorDrawable contents to be sure.

Comment: hmmm, I should have provided that info. It happens to the ImageView and also the background for the constraintlayout. For the ImageView, app:srcCompat is being used and for the constraintlayout we are using android:background. I cannot upload the actual image because it is the company property. The link of this apple image: https://publicdomainvectors.org/download.php?file=zeimusu_Apple.svg